# Product and Sum of Polynomial Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

The ratio of the sum of the roots of the equation, $8x^3+px^2-2x+1=0 $  to the product of the roots of the equation $5x^3+7x^3-3x+q=0 $ is $3:2$. What is the value $\frac{p-q}{p+q}$?

Well I found out the sum of the roots of 1st equation is $-\frac{p}{8}$ and product of roots of second equation is $-\frac{d}{5}$.

Now what to do further? How to get in terms of $\frac{p-q}{p+q} $ ?

Comment: Please use LateX (directions in the FAQ section) or, at least and to begin with, parentheses: what is $\,p-q/p+q\,$? Did you mean $$\frac{p-q}{p+q}\;,\;\;p-\frac qp+q\;,\;\;p-\frac q{p+q}\ldots ??$$

Comment: oh..yeah...the 1st one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Vieta's Formulas](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Vieta%27s_Formulas),

the sum of the roots of  $\ 8x^3+px^2-2x+1=0$ is $\frac{-p}8$

and the product of the roots of $\ 5x^3+7x^3-3x+q=0$ is $\frac {-q}5$

So, $$\frac {\frac{-p}8}{\frac {-q}5}=\frac32\implies \frac pq=\frac{3\cdot 8}{2\cdot 5}=\frac{12}5$$

Now, use [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo)

or use $$\frac{p-q}{p+q}=\frac{\frac pq-1}{\frac pq+1}=\frac{\frac {12}5-1}{\frac {12}5+1}=\frac{12-5}{12+5}$$

or use  $$\frac p{12}=\frac q5=r(\ne0)\text{(say)}\implies p=12r,q=5r$$

Comment: OH yeah! c & d! well, after this it shud be $$\frac{24-10}{10+10}$$  ...???

Comment: @joeyrohan, no, it should be $$\frac{24-10}{24+10}$$  or we can use $$\frac{p-q}{p+q}=\frac{\frac pq-1}{\frac pq+1}=\frac{\frac {24}{10}-1}{\frac {24}{10}+1}=\frac{24-10}{24+10}$$

Comment: But 7/17 is not in the options.These are : 3/2,2/3,2/5,1/5 !!!

Comment: Then either you miscopied the question or they have a mistake in the options for the answer.

Comment: @joeyrohan, please cross the question & the options. But I believe learning the method is more important than matching the answer(s) supplied

Comment: @DonAntonio I am sure..like 100%..the question is correct..n options can't be wrong !

Comment: "Options can't be wrong"?? Like when someone writes down something...he can't be wrong?! You honestly think?

Comment: @joeyrohan, sounds like an oracle. Could you really follow the method used here? Correct method always leads to the correct answer.

Comment: They are MCA top university papers..well, but the method here is right...so have to accept it :)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the ques. is from DU MCA 2011...That's why!!

Comment: @joeyrohan, is it available online?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee yup https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8gUa0bct5D_ZGpBV2owV2ZIdkE/edit?usp=drive_web

Comment: @labbhattacharjee i got it...may the options are wrong!!

Comment: What is MCA, DU MCA...and why being from the latter one "explains" the mistake in the options?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

The given ratio is (notice: is $\,q\,$ , not $\,d\,$ )

$$\frac{\frac p8}{\frac q5}=\frac{5p}{8q}$$

Get from here the solution to your question, whatever it is.

Comment: Yeah..this much i solved...$$\frac{5p}{8q}$$ = 3/2 .but what's next?

Comment: $$\frac{5p}{8q}=\frac32\implies 5p=12q\implies q=\frac{5}{12}p\implies$$

$$\frac{p-q}{p+q}=\frac{\frac7{12}p}{\frac{17}{12}p}=\ldots$$